# What is the difference between prefix/postfix and increment operator

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void h (int *p) { *p++; }
int main ( )
{
    int index = 100;
    h(&index);
    printf("%d\n",index);
}
```

This code gives 100 but the one below gives 101 as output. Are not `i+=1` and `i++` same thing?

```
#include<stdio.h>
void h (int *p) { *p+=1; }
int main ( )
{
    int index = 100;
    h(&index);
    printf("%d\n",index);
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: `++` has precendence over `*`, but `*` has precedence over `+=`. Therefore  `*p++` is actually `*(p++)`, whereas `*p+=1` is `(*p)+=1`.

Comment: Can you please write this as an answer so I can close the question.

Comment: ++*p will give you the equivalent of *p+=1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all a matter of **operator precedence**. The complete list is [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

`++` has precendence over `*` (dereferencing), but `*` has precedence over `+=`.

Therefore:
`*p++` is actually `*(p++)`,
whereas `*p+=1` is `(*p)+=1`.

In the first case, `*p++`, the increment is performed on the pointer `p` and has no effect on the `int` it points to. (Also, the pointer `p` is a local parameter, so changes to it have no effect in the calling routine.)

In the second case, `*p+=1`, the increment is performed on `*p`, so the `int` that `p` points to is changed.

Comment: Is operator precedence different in C++ vs. C? In C, ++ and * are of equal precedence (associated right to left). Given *p++, p is incremented after being dereferenced. *++p gives the behavior you describe in the 1st case explanation. 

Sorry, not a C++ guy.

Comment: @PaulLynch this is [c++ operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). In general similar to c. I haven't checked whether there is a specific case where they disagree. In any case I always recommend to use `()` and **not** rely on the precendence rules. This makes the code clearer and less prone to bugs due to misunderstanding of precedence.

Comment: Re “This means that in the 1st case the increment is done before dereferencing”: The increment may be done at any time from the start of `h` to its return. `p++` means the value of `p` before the increment is used for the remainder of the expression, but the increment itself may be done before this or after this, including before and/or after the entire rest of the expression. `*p++` could be “Remember `p`, increment `p`, get the `int` where the remembered value points” (and discard it, since it is not used) or it could be “Get the `int` where `p` points, increment `p`.”

Comment: Or `p` could be non-atomic, so `*p++` could be “Remember the value of `p`. Update the lower half of `p` to the incremented value. Get the `int` where the remembered value points. Update the upper half of `p` to the incremented value.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil I was actually stuggling a bit with the wording, but I think the general issue the OP raised is addressed by my answer. I edited and tried to make it more accurate, please feel free to edit and improve.

Comment: Eric makes a very good point, since *(p++) doesn't change precedence. Interesting that there are differences in precedence (i.e. postfix vs. prefix). Thanks, all.